# Generate stream in racket

Tags: racket

I'm trying to generate a stream in racket that contains a sequence of 1 or 2 element lists.
It should start with the number one in a list and every subsequent element of the stream is incremented by one with the added requirement of even numbers should be duplicated in the list.
For example: ((1)(2 2)(3)(4 4)(5)(6 6))

How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It's a 2-step process:

1. Create stream like 1, 2, 3, 4. ... using [`in-range`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-range#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-range%29%29) or [`in-naturals`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-range#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-naturals%29%29)
2. Map over each element to transform them into lists with [`stream-map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html?q=in-range#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-map%29%29)

This code snippet shows a way to create infinite as well as bounded "even-odd" lazy streams:

```
#lang racket

; (-> Nat (U (list Nat Nat) (list Nat)))
; a pair of `nat` if nat is even, singleton list otherwise
(define (nat->stream-elem nat)
  (if (even? nat) (list nat nat) (list nat)))

; (->* () (Nat) (stream-of (U (list Nat Nat) (list Nat))))
; a stream with `total`, infinite stream if no arg provided
(define (even-odd-stream [total false])
  (stream-map nat->stream-elem (if total (in-range 1 (+ total 1)) (in-naturals 1))))

; (-> Nat Void)
; displays first `to-display` elements from `stream`
(define (display-stream to-display stream)
  (for ([i to-display] [e stream])
    (displayln e)))


; Displays all 6 elements of a 6-element even-odd-stream
(display-stream 6 (even-odd-stream 6))

(displayln "- - -")

; Displays first 10 elements of an infinite even-odd-stream
(display-stream 10 (even-odd-stream))
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function, `sc`, say, which takes one argument, `n` say.  It should return:

- if its argument is even `(stream-cons (list n n) (sc (+ n 1)))`;
- if its argument is odd `(stream-cons (list n) (sc (+ n 1)))`.

`(sc 1)` is the stream you want.